# How can i divide my html list into multiple columns while using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

> I have a html list of the form:

```html
<ul id="cols">

<li class="nav-li"> list 1 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 2 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 3 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 4 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 5 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 6 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 7 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 8 </li>
<li class="nav-li"> list 9 </li>

</ul>
```

I want this list to be divided into 2 columns for which i am using:

```css
#cols {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Secondly i want to change the order of list elements for which i am using the following snippet:

```css
#cols {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#cols li:first-child {
  order: 4;
}

#cols li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 5;
}

#cols li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

#cols li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}
```

But when i combine both CSS i.e.

```css
#cols {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}

#cols li:first-child {
  order: 4;
}

#cols li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 5;
}

#cols li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

#cols li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}
```

The division of the list into 2 columns property gets removed!
Basically flex property and column property seems to be in contradiction!
How can i run both these conditions simultaneously, i.e splitting into columns and reordering list elements?

http://jsfiddle.net/3jtfn2ad/39/

Comment: can you share what you are expecting , like how the list should be shown ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d6u802ty/1/

Answer (score 1):

first of all flex is not 2d if you want to have 2d structure and control it , go for css grid.
Coming to your question if you choose flex direction as column , all the flex item will got in one column , so you need to find a way how we can show 2 columns and structure items.
if you are defining orders , the li(flex items) which dont have order will have 0 by default.

```css
#cols  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

#cols .nav-li{
/* divide it into two column with equal width */
  flex-basis: 50%
}

/* if you want the other items at last change the orders for all to last */
/*
#cols .nav-li{
  order: 6;
}*/
#cols li:first-child{
  order: 4;
}

#cols li:nth-child(2){
  order: 5;
}

#cols li:nth-child(3){
  order: 3;
}

#cols li:nth-child(4){
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="cols">

  <li class="nav-li"> list 1 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 2 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 3 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 4 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 5 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 6 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 7 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 8 </li>
  <li class="nav-li"> list 9 </li>

</ul>
```

Hope this helps.